# How to mirror a 3D mesh on the X axis

Tags: c++, 3d, hlsl, gltf

I am working on a C++ 3D game and I am having trouble with how the mesh looks when I am loading it from a glTF file on the screen.
[This](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/BoomBox/glTF) is the 3D model I am trying to load.

I am using DirectX 11.

[image: Boombox I loaded]

As you can see the mesh is flipped on the X-axis and I can't figure what to do to flip to look normal.

[image: Boombox correct]

This is how I want it to look.

```
    struct VS_INPUT
    {
        float4 position: POSITION0;
        float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
        float3 normal: NORMAL0;
    };
    
    struct VS_OUTPUT
    {
        float4 position: SV_POSITION;
        float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
        float3 normal: NORMAL0;
        float3 direction_to_camera: TEXCOORD1;
    };
    
    
    cbuffer constant: register(b0)
    {
        row_major float4x4 m_world;
        row_major float4x4 m_view;
        row_major float4x4 m_proj;
    
        float4 m_light_direction;
        float4 m_camera_position;
    
        float4 m_light_position;
        float m_light_radius;
    };
    
    
    
    VS_OUTPUT vsmain(VS_INPUT input)
    {
        VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    
        // WORLD SPACE
        output.position = mul(input.position, m_world);
        output.direction_to_camera = normalize(output.position - m_camera_position.xyz);
        // VIEW SPACE
        output.position = mul(output.position, m_view);
        // SCREEN SPACE
        output.position = mul(output.position, m_proj);
    
    
        output.texcoord = input.texcoord;
        output.normal = normalize(mul(input.normal, m_world));
        return output;
    }
```

This is the vertex shader I am using.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.position.x = -output.position.x; in vertex shader
```

or when loading your mesh and parsing vertices invert x coordinate of vertex.

```
v.x = -v.x;
```

or scaling -1 on x axis should do the trick.

```
SetScale( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
```

Comment: I have inverted the x axis when parsing the vertices but it seems the mesh turn inside out
https://imgur.com/a/HtjoVV9
https://imgur.com/a/aOR040k

Comment: try in vertex shader and tell me ...

Comment: the exact same result for vertex shader :(

Comment: Try scaling -1 on x axis

Comment: i have inverted the scale on the x-axis, but the result seems to be the same
https://imgur.com/a/dLk2GB9

Comment: share your project with me. with assets

Comment: If you use negative scale on just one axis (which all of those three methods do), your triangle winding order gets inverted as well. This could be fixed at loading time by swapping two vertices of each triangle, otherwise you have to switch your backface/frontface (clockwise vs coutner-clockwise) culling to account for that. Also, if you use normals/etc for lighting purposes, remember to flip them as well.

Comment: That was what I needed, now it works as expected, thanks a lot!